# Unable to access javascript property

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a javascript code to bind a jQuery colorbox to my element, but cant figure out how to change the value of the property inside the callback:

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({
    iframe: true, 
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    onLoad: function() {
        console.log(width);
    },
});
```

Why do I get `ReferenceError: width is not defined` or how do I access this property?

Comment: I don't think you can read the property directly from the `colourbox` object. You need to get the width of the generated HTML element itself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hmm, so no way to have a pointer to that object even inside its callback?

Comment: The object is passed and read by the plugin, you generally can't change the object later unless the plugin exposes a way to do so.

Comment: @Ulterior: thre is no way to get a reference to the object in general. There might be a way that is specific to that library you are using (for example, what happens if you do `console.log(this)`?

Comment: @Ulterior that depends on what properties are passed to the callback. I'm not familiar with colorbox. I should mention that what I said applies if you are trying to get the `px` value of the width. If you just want `80%` returned, you can use the method hugomg described in his answer.

Comment: ok, let me ask it another way - can I set a new value to that property before the ```colorbox``` loads, so I can ```override``` it?

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because width is just a property of the object you are passing to the colorbox function. Its not a variable you can reference.

They doing this:

```
var myWidth = '80%';

$(".iframe").colorbox   ({
    iframe:true, 
    width: myWidth,
    height:'80%',
    onLoad:function() {

        console.log( myWidth );   

    },
});
```

or this

```
var props = {
    iframe:true, 
    width: '80%',
    height:'80%',
    onLoad:function() {

        console.log( props.width );   

    },
};

$(".iframe").colorbox(props);
```

Comment: is there a way to change or set the ```width``` variable in my callback function?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access a `width` variable in the global scope. Sort of like trying to use `document`, `window`, or `$`. What you want to access is the `width` property of the colorbox object. If the plugin binds `this` to the colorbox object then you could do something like this:

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({
    ...
    onLoad: function() {
        console.log(this.width);
    }
});
```

But I assume you're trying to access the width of the element you're binding the colorbox to. If that's the case, you may try something like this:

```
var $iframe = $(".iframe");
$iframe.colorbox({
    ...
    onLoad: function() {
        console.log($iframe.width());
    }
});
```

Comment: this.width - undefined

Comment: Like I said, that depends on if they bind the object to the `onLoad` function, which doesn't appear to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your `onLoad` function:

```
onLoad: function() {
    console.log($(this).width());
}
```

Comment: I get ```21``` what is this about? :)

Comment: its the width of the `iframe`

Comment: in what measurements? pixels? percents?

Comment: is measured in pixels

Comment: impossible... my colorbox is like 1000px wide

Comment: probably when rendered this iframe grows, on load it appeared to be that width

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I want by using the:

```
width: function() {

}
```

this way I can programmatically override the width variable, which I was trying to do...